# Dini function measurable for continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $F$ is continuous on $[a, b]$. Show that,
$$D^+(F)(x) = \limsup_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ h > 0}} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$
is measurable.

I wonder whether the following "proof" of this statement is correct. I'm very much in doubt due to the continuity being only supposed on $[a, b]$. I sort of ignored it, not knowing what to do with it. Is the statement even through without supposing continuity everywhere (that is taking $a = -\infty, b = +\infty$)?

---

Proof:
We must show that Dini function $D^+(F)(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{0<h<\delta} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{0<h<\frac{1}{n}} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h}$ is a measurable. In particular then, we are done if we show that $\forall \delta > 0$, $\sup_{0<h<\delta} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h}$ is measurable. Suppose therefore for arbitrary $\delta > 0$ and $\alpha$ that $x_0 \in F_{\delta, \alpha} = \{x : \sup_{0<h<\delta} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h} > \alpha\}$, we show that there exists some ball containing $x_0$ that is entirely contained in $F_{\delta, \alpha}$, then $F_{\delta, \alpha}$ is open and hence measurable, and we are done.

For $x_0$ we have some $h_0 < \delta$ such that $\frac{F(x_0+h_0) - F(x_0)}{h_0} > \alpha$. Now consider the open interval $O = \{x : |x| < \delta_O\}$, by continuity taking $\delta_O$ small enough we have for any $\epsilon > 0$, however small, $\forall o \in O$ simultaneously that $F(x_0+o+h_0)-F(x_0+h_0) > -\epsilon/2$ and $F(x_0+o)-F(x_0) < \epsilon/2$, and therefore
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    &\frac{F(x_0+o+h_0) - F(x_0+o)}{h_0} \\
    =& \frac{(F(x_0+o+h_0) - F(x_0+h_0)) + F(x_0+h_0) - (F(x_0+o) - F(x_0) + F(x_0))}{h_0} \\
    >& -\epsilon/h_0 + \frac{F(x_0+h_0) - F(x_0)}{h_0} > \alpha \text{ when taking $\epsilon$ small enough}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
so that $x_0 + O$ is an open ball containing $x_0$ and being contained in $F_{\delta, \alpha}$.

---

Thank-you so much for all the help!